# What are the  dimensions of a 110 film cartridge?

Tags: film, diy, 110

I'm looking for the exact dimensions of the 110 film cartridge. I'll take any sort of information including the ISO whitepaper for it (which I would *love* to read), or if someone already has it in AutoCAD that would save me all the trouble.

Comment: I think a rhino file would be more useful, especially if you actually wanted to fabricate one.

Comment: How do you plan on doing this?

Comment: On a related tangent, we might soon have digital 126 cartridges: http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2011/04/digital-film-concept-could-resurrect-dead-film-cameras/

Answer (score 9):

Ah my knowledge of the ridiculous and obscure may come in handy!
You want ISO 13450 (1996), which has all the juicy details on 110 film (size/shape of the cartridge, exposure area, speeds, etc.).

Sadly I'm not sure where you can get a copy without forking over the Swiss Francs to the ISO folks - Perhaps someone else has a hook-up though.

---

Perhaps also helpful - I *think* 110 is just a smaller 126 cartridge (it's been a while since I shot anything that wasn't 35mm or sheets/plates - someone correct me if I'm wrong).
 If you can turn up a CAD document for a 126 cartridge you can shrink it 'till it fits...

Comment: It is a smaller version of the 126.  I cant believe I didnt know there was 126 film, Im a bit upset with myself for that!  Although its smaller by 35% in height and 54% smaller in the width that doesnt tell me what the dimensions of the case are.  Im just trying to avoid taking one of the rolls I have, destroying it and taking calipers to it.

Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: I wouldn't be above calipers -- I'd be interested in trying to print it on a Makerbot myself.

Comment: As far as destroying a capsule, why not simply ask for a bunch of already developed capsules?